# How to install ubuntu running iniside VirtualBox on Mac Air

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, macbook-air, netboot

Having configured a virtual machine for Ubuntu on Virtual-box on my mac air I need to install Ubuntu OS itself. I have selected the hard-drive as the primary boot device and the network as the secondary boot device, so I am not prompted to install an Ubuntu disk at boot time. It attempts to net-boot but is unable to locate Ubuntu and I cannot find anywhere in the configuration where I can explicitly specify where to find an Ubuntu image, so I assume it reverts to some default location and fails.

Has anybody out there ever successfully installed Ubuntu on virtual box on their Mac Air? What steps did you take to get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Not on a Macbook Air, but I'm sure the process is the same.  In the settings for the Ubuntu VM, go to Storage -> IDE controller and click the "Empty" subsection.  On the right hand side you'll see a dropdown menu with a CD icon next to it.  Click the CD.  Browse to the image.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you open VirtualBox, click on NEW and create your virtual machine. You can basically keep clicking next until you are back at the start menu.
2. Select your new machine, and click Start. This will open a Wizard that will guide you through the installation process. You will need to download an Ubuntu .iso image from their website. You will use it as the installation media. If your Macbook is from this year or last year, get the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 12.04.
3. You will then go through the standard Ubuntu installation (in the virtual computer, of course). When you are done, be sure to install VM extensions (when you restart the first time, Ubuntu will offer "Additional Drivers", which allow the OS to interact better with the virtual hardware.
4. You can further customize your machine when it is powered off, by right clicking on it and going to preferences.